# HTML/CSS body isnt at the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with my HTMl/CSS. it seems like my body tag has somehow got a margin-top of 10px... However I cannot find anyway to get rid of it. The other websites I have built has never done this, so any help would be appreciated.

THE CODE:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js_plugins/skrollr.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text.css">
        <title>MyPage</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div id="maincontent">
            <section id="maincontent-sect-intro" >
                <div id="maincontent-sect-intro-content">
                    <p class="name-intro">Introduction</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
div#maincontent
{
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}
section
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
}
/*
For intro section
*/
section#maincontent-sect-intro
{
    background-color: #666666;
    text-align: center;
}
div#maincontent-sect-intro-content
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `html { padding: 0; }`?

Comment: add `.name-intro{margin: 0;}` in your css - http://jsfiddle.net/czc84qd6/

Comment: @Paul padding is not the problem here, the margin value is, but OP has set that in body and should have no white-space there....

Comment: @MaryMelody, it worked thank you. how come a p tag have such a big margin top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is the p class "name-intro" `<p>` tags automatically give a margin top of 1em. just add this to your css

```
.name-intro {
  margin: 0;
}
```

also a rule of thumb, when specifying 0 values, never add pixel or em, just leave it as zero :)

Comment: This is the correct solution. Headings can cause similar problems. Another solution is to add `overflow: auto` to the parent element of the child causing the margin problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set padding and margin both.

```
padding:0
margin: 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You might have to change the CSS to :

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```